# Would my mini math web platform be useful to anyone else?

Tags: discussion

(I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this, but it seemed more appropriate than the main math site...)

So I got sick of keeping all my notes spread across Mathematica and vi, and wrote a tiny website platform to let me do my math musings and easily share things. Basically, I wanted something that let me quickly and easily jot down stuff with markdown and latex.

I've been using it for months and it's great for me, but I have no idea whether anyone else would be interested in this sort of thing. So if you want, see it / try it / use it at http://stacked.by.tc.

If there is interest, maybe I'll try to polish it up some and release it into the wild. If there's not, that's fine too, less work for me. :)

Comment: you also might try the mathematica  stackexchange.

Comment: It looks nice.  Is it a combination of MathJax and MarkDown packages?  Are you thinking of releasing it as open source for others to incorporate into their web development, or as a website for end users?

Comment: Oh, you said MatheMATICA. Good call.  And @Matt
 It is, I nicked some nice third party package that had both of them after struggling with it myself. I was thinking more the former, since I figure it's probably too niche for the latter...

Comment: Thanks for let us know about your page. You could also promote your page in the chatrooms.

Comment: Couldn't see pictures you've linked to. For instance in the conjecture about representation of integers by powers of $(3,5,7)$. Clicking the links to the pictures only reopens the page.

Comment: I like to use [Typora](https://www.typora.io/) for lightweight latex editing. Your project also slightly reminds me of a [mini blogging platform](https://github.com/geajack/charlotte) I made which comes with Mathjax by default, although the design priorities are probably different.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it! Having more platforms to do maths more easily is always great! Just wondering: is there any benefits using your website over other platforms like Overleaf (I just started to use the latter a few ago)?

Comment: Heh... I use overleaf and discord to jot things down.

Comment: I'd find this more useful if it were possible to make notes without having to make an account. You'd then be able to refer to individual notes via unique URLs.